# how can i make the li inside the div be horizontal?

Tags: css, html, html-lists

how can I make the li inside the "menu" div be horizontal and if its bigger than the "menu" div then how could I make a slider to the left or right?

now this is the **HTML**`

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul style="text-align: center; background-color: #003366; display: inline ; position: center; list-style-type: none;">
        <li onClick="location.href = ''">how has the Internet impacted teens?</li>
        <li onClick="location.href = ''">how has the Internet impacted teens?</li>
        <li onClick="location.href = ''">how has the Internet impacted teens?</li>
        <li onClick="location.href = ''">how has the Internet impacted teens?</li>
        <li onClick="location.href = ''">how has the Internet impacted teens?</li>
    </ul>
</div>
 <h1 id="panel11">In what way has the Internet impacted teens?</h1>

<div id="person">......................</div>
<div id="person1">......................</div>
<div id="person2">......................</div>
<div id="person3">......................</div>
<div id="person4">......................</div>
<div id="person5">......................</div>
<div id="person6">......................</div>
<div id="person7">......................</div>
<div id="person8">......................</div>
<div id="person9">......................</div>
```

and now here is the **CSS**

```
#menu {
    margin-top:60px;
    margin-left:500px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #003366;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    position: center;
    list-style-type: none;
}
body {
    background-color: green;
    margin: auto;
}
h1 {
    background-color: #FF0D0D;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:99;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#person {
    float:left;
    clear:right;
    background-color: orange;
    margin-top:100px;
}
#person1 {
    float:right;
    clear:left;
    background-color: orange;
}
#person2 {
    float:left;
    clear:right;
    background-color: orange;
}
```

its the same for the rest of the "person" divs. I've looked around the internet and I had found one but I just cant remember the website in which I had found it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the `li` elements appear in a row, you have to add the `display:inline` property to them and the `white-space:nowrap` property to their parent `ul` or the `#menu div`, so the line won't be broken.

If you want to have a horizontal scrollbar that appears automatically in case the window/screen is narrower than the menu, you must use the `overflow:auto` property applied to the parent `ul` or the ancestor `#menu div`

I've also cleaned up the `#menu div` CSS: `position:center` is not valid, `text-align:center` is twice, etc.

Anyway, it's recommended putting the CSS together, so try to avoid using the `style` attribute in the HTML tags.

This is the CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;

}
li {
    display: inline;
}
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/LbA7Q/3/

Comment: wow! Thank you so much! haha something so simple that made a big change. Thanks again! :) now my Senior project will have a better look :) Thanks again one last time.

Answer (score 0):

Float left on the li elements, that on the up you have to set a fixed size so all li get the width they need. If the screen is smaller than the ul.

Comment: So by making them float left they'll all be horizontal? That's how I want them to be. I tried the "inline" code but it just moves the whole Div up on top of the webpage, it doesn't do much. I've tried the inline-block and block-inline but they just remove everything of css on the div.

Comment: Yes then they will float left in the UL element. But you need to set the width in the ul and the li so they all can fit in one row.

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Fwm6H/**

HTML :

```
<div class="person_container">
    <div id="person" class="persons">Hi</div>
    <div id="person1" class="persons">Hi</div>
    <div id="person2" class="persons">Hi</div>
    <div id="person3" class="persons">Hi</div>
    <div id="person4" class="persons">Hi</div>
    <div id="person5" class="persons">Hi</div>
    <div id="person6" class="persons">Hi</div>
    <div id="person7" class="persons">Hi</div>
    <div id="person8" class="persons">Hi</div>
    <div id="person9" class="persons">Hi</div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.person_container{
    width:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:auto;
    border:1px solid #000;
    font-size:0;
}
.persons{
    display:inline-block;
    background:#dadada;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Comment: thanks but I wanted to do that for the "menu" div. And if it's bigger because I know it is going to be bigger then how do I make it have a scroller to the left and right? I also wanted to make it horizontal I've tried putting the inline code but it just moves the whole div to the top(I tried it on google Chrome) and I'm not sure how many pixels the school computers have because I'm going to be presenting this webpage as my Senior project so all the help is greatly appreciated :)